# How to Deque and sorting priorityqueue using heap correctly?

Tags: python, heap, priority-queue

My homework is to create priorityqueue by having user input in this format
*Number Of case*
*case-type* *caseID* *priority*
with 1 as highest priority

> Example.
>   16
>   I 0 2
>   I 1 2
>   D
>   I 3 3
>   I 4 1
>   D
>   I 6 1
>   D
>   I 8 1
>   D
>   I 10 2
>   I 11 1
>   I 12 3
>   I 13 2
>   I 14 3
>   I 15 2

(I mean normal case, D mean deque the highest priority at that time) and then print the remain caseID sort by priority

This is my code

```
import heapq
priority=[]

num=int(input())
for i in range (0,num,1):
    temp=input()
    if (len(temp)>1):
        casetype,caseID,casePrio,=temp.split(" ",2)
        heapq.heappush(priority, (int(caseID),int(casePrio)))
    else:
        heapq.heappop(priority)

for i in range(len(priority)):
    print (priority[i][1])
```

I expect to get this output

> Output:
>   11
>   1
>   10
>   13
>   15
>   3
>   12
>   14

but get this instead

> Output:
>   11
>   1
>   10
>   15
>   12
>   13
>   14
>   3

Comment: A heap *isn't sorted* - only the root element has a fixed location, everything else respects the heap invariant (parent less than either child), but is otherwise in arbitrary order.

Comment: Just a personal note, and maybe it's because I'm terrible at this, but I don't think your objects are named in an easily understandable way. For example, I see in your instructions you have `number of case` `case-type` `caseID` and `priority`... and in your code you have `pio` `num` `tic` `z` `x` `y`. For someone reading your code/this homework for the first time, I had to go back and forth to figure out what was for what.

Comment: I'm not following your expected output.  Perhaps add some details on why you skip ids 6 and 8.  Also in python, deque is a double-ended queue.  You are using deque as a verb, which I don't understand.  Do you mean dequeue?

Comment: @pylang 6 and 8 are skipped because they're removed from the heap with the 3rd and 4th 'D' commands. And, yes, he should have used "dequeue" rather than "deque".

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the priority queue is that when you pop something, it gives you the highest-priority item that's currently in the queue. You don't need to sort the thing yourself. That's just doing extra work.

If you want to output the remainder of the queue in priority order, you can replace your final loop with this:

```
while (len(priority) > 0)
    print(heapq.heappop(priority));
```

Each call to `heappop` will return the highest priority item still in the queue.

Don't count on getting exactly the output you expect, however. `heapq` does not guarantee the removal order of items that have equal priority. For example, if you were to insert items in this order:

```
10 1
11 2
12 2
13 3
```

And then remove them, the result will be `10 11 12 13`. But if you changed the insertion order to:

```
10 1
13 3
11 2
12 2
```

Then the output will be `10 12 11 13`.

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. It is the correct answer.